# There are no products in your shopping cart

Tags: ubercart

I'm using Ubercart in a Drupal 6 setup.I have created products and able to order the products as an authenticated user mode ,but when i go with anonymous buying it doesn't showing any products in cart page and it results "There are no products in your shopping cart." when click add to cart button.

For me its working good in live site , when i took live dump to my testing site , am facing above bug (There are no products in your shopping cart.) please help if anyone knows the solution for this .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue might be a MySQL problem. I'm assuming here that you dump the live DB and load it in your test machine.

Please check the uid value for the anonymous user in "users" table. The anonymous user is the one with empty fields. The uid value should be 0.

With certain MySQL configurations when loading sql dumps, autoincremental fields cannot accept the 0 value, and gives an incremented value.

Comment: Yes You are correct thanks for your reply ermannob .